# generate surrogate data in R

Tags: r

I have a binary time series with 359 observations. 
like this; 0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
...
I want to generate  n data samples  with same intervals but permuted order.
For this at first I found times which original data became one from zero something like this:

```
147 65 10 251
```

and then randomized the order of intervals into something like these:

```
251 10 65 147
10  251  147 65
.
. 
.
```

and so far my code is something like this:

```
mydata <- "C:/Users/me/Desktop/2.xlsx"
library("xlsx")
library("tseries")
my_data <-  read.xlsx(mydata, sheetName = "Sheet1", header = F)
file <- "C:/Users/me/Desktop/pp.xlsx"
ts=my_data[6]
ts=unlist(ts)

for (i in 1:100){
  diff.ts<-diff(ts)
  x=sample(diff(which(diff.ts==1)))
  print(x)
  write.xlsx(x,file[i], sheetName = "Sheet1",col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=FALSE, password=NULL)
}
```

however,

1. I can not store all of these in .xlsx file even though while printing they seem fine
2. my second problem is that I do not only want to know which time 0 to one happened but also I want to write them as the original data for example if in one of the randomized samples the intervals is 10  251 147  65 I want a stored column with 1 in the 10th, 251th, 147th and 65th row as one and the other row as zero something like this :

   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 .... .

Sorry for English errors

Comment: This isn't making sense to me. If you have times that are all the same then time time series of "pulses" will be identical. Perhaps you want the intervals to be the same but in a permuted order?

Comment: I also struggle to understand what you're trying to do. What is a *"binary time series"*? Your sample data suggests a simple permutation of the form `x<-c(147, 65, 10, 251); sample(x, length(x))`. Can you please provide some more details including a somewhat larger and more representative sample dataset with expected output?

Comment: Thank you very much; I actually want intervals to be same but permuted order as you suggested and my time series is something like;0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
and here I found the occurrence of "1" and I want the same intervals in randomized order for 100 samples.

Comment: @SarinaHoseini *"and here I found the occurrence of "1" and I want the same intervals in randomized order for 100 samples"* I'm sorry but I have no idea what you mean. What intervals? Which 100 samples? Your "time-series" seems to be a binary vector. What do you mean by "found the occurrence of '1'"? Can you please edit your main post (don't put critical information in comments) and provide more details (sample data and -- very importantly -- expected output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interval objective is unclear and your permutated interval question is perhaps answered with the sample() function below, which will randomly pick a distribution of 1s and 0s.  You can also adjust the probabilities to change change a 0 or 1 is selected, here it's 50/50%.  Additionally, if you want a random sample but to ensure your code is repeatable, you can enforce a random seed in your session to draw the same permutation each time with: `set.seed(123456)`, picking whatever seed you feel appropriate.

```
sample(x=c(0,1),size=359,replace=T,prob=c(0.5,0.5))
```

Alternatively, your question might suggest wanting to set values equal to 1 at a specific index.  Here, for your example of 147,65,10,251 you can do:

```
intervals <- rep(0,359)
intervals[c(147,65,10,251)] <- 1
```

Or perhaps like this?

```
intervals <- rep(0,359)
intervals[sample(c(147,65,10,251))]  <- 1
```

As this is a two part question and an answer to your excel writing issue: you have the write.xlsx called from within the for loop, meaning that you're writing the file at each loop.  This may or may not be the behavior you want?  I assume writing the entire dataset is preferable.   However, as you're specifying file[i] as the output, and your variable file is a single value (or one-length vector) you'll get errors.  You change this in the write.xlsx to `write.xlsx(x,paste0("my_file_num",i,".xlsx"), ...` or move the call outside the loop as illustrated below

```
file <- "C:/Users/me/Desktop/pp.xlsx"
ts=my_data[6]
ts=unlist(ts)
samples <- NULL
for (i in 1:100){
  diff.ts<-diff(ts)
  x=sample(diff(which(diff.ts==1)))
  samples <- append(samples,list(samples=x))
  print(x)
}

  write.xlsx(samples,file, sheetName = "Sheet1",col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=FALSE, password=NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you very much now it works as I want, however my remained question is that I want these numbers as row indices intervals where they would represent one. Any suggestion ? Now the inputs are like:
18
23
20
35
5
16
8
30
26
13
10
34
26
16
23
19
10
16
and I want array with 359 samples all zero except for these rows of these intervals as one

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand, really.  The commenters above I think have also requested clarifications.  As best I understand, you want a sequence of 0 or 1 values whose permutation changes according your 359 observations.  If this is what you need, you may use: sample(x=c(0,1),size=359,replace=T)
I've updated my answer above to include this, but it's not clear if this is what you're seeking?

Comment: Thank you very much. My English is really bad

Comment: No, problem.  Happy to help.  I've made some edits to the answer with various interpretations to your question.  I hope some of these suggestions help you to find your solution.